# Making RecyclerView clickable not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been working on making my RecyclerView list clickable. I have not successfully retrieve any results from clicks yet. I have searched through stackoverflow and youtube, but not understanding what I am implementing wrong. My Adapter is

**Food Adapter**

```
ublic class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder> {

private Context mCtx;
private List<Food> foodList;

public FoodAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Food> foodList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.foodList = foodList;
}


@Override
public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    FoodViewHolder foodView = new FoodViewHolder(view, mCtx, foodList);

    return foodView;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.txtFoodTitle.setText(food.getFoodTitle());
    holder.txtFoodDesc.setText(food.getFoodDesc());
    holder.txtFoodLoc.setText(food.getFoodLoc() + ", CA");
    holder.txtFoodAuthor.setText(food.getFoodAuthor());
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(food.getImage(), null));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodList.size();
}

class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtFoodTitle, txtFoodDesc, txtFoodLoc, txtFoodAuthor;
    List<Food> foods;
    Context ctx;

    public FoodViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, List<Food> foods) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.foods = foods;
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodImg);
        txtFoodTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodTitle);
        txtFoodDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
        txtFoodLoc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodLoc);
        txtFoodAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodAuthor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        //Food food = this.foods.get(position);
        Log.i(TAG, "Clicked!");

    }
}
}
```

**FragmentList**

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_list, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    final FoodAdapter adapter;

    final List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    adapter = new FoodAdapter(getActivity(), foodList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    String url = "url";
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i(TAG, response);
            try {
                JSONArray foodResp = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < foodResp.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject foodObj = foodResp.getJSONObject(i);
                    foodList.add(
                            new Food(
                                    foodObj.getInt("u_id"),
                                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,
                                    foodObj.getString("mealTitle"),
                                    foodObj.getString("mealDesc"),
                                    foodObj.getString("cityName"),
                                    foodObj.getString("userName")
                    ));
                }

                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "err: " + error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("data", "value");

            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(sr);

    return v;
}
```

One of the original videos I was watching showed it done with an ArrayList<>, but I already set up my RecyclerView with List. I do not imagine that that would matter. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set Click Listener in your `FragmentList.java`.

**Food Adapter**

```
public class FoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder> {

private Context mCtx;
private List<Food> foodList;

public FoodAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Food> foodList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.foodList = foodList;
}

public static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.FoodViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtFoodTitle, txtFoodDesc, txtFoodLoc, txtFoodAuthor;
    //List<Food> foods;
    //Context ctx;

    public FoodViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodImg);
        txtFoodTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodTitle);
        txtFoodDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
        txtFoodLoc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodLoc);
        txtFoodAuthor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodAuthor);
    }
}

@Override
public FoodAdapter.FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return FoodViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Food food = foodList.get(position);
    holder.txtFoodTitle.setText(food.getFoodTitle());
    holder.txtFoodDesc.setText(food.getFoodDesc());
    holder.txtFoodLoc.setText(food.getFoodLoc() + ", CA");
    holder.txtFoodAuthor.setText(food.getFoodAuthor());
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(food.getImage(), null));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodList.size();
}

}
```

**FragmentList**

```
public class FragmentList extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_list, container, false);
    final FoodAdapter adapter;

    final List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    adapter = new FoodAdapter(getActivity(), foodList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    String url = "url";
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i(TAG, response);
            try {
                JSONArray foodResp = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < foodResp.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject foodObj = foodResp.getJSONObject(i);
                    foodList.add(
                            new Food(
                                    foodObj.getInt("u_id"),
                                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,
                                    foodObj.getString("mealTitle"),
                                    foodObj.getString("mealDesc"),
                                    foodObj.getString("cityName"),
                                    foodObj.getString("userName")
                    ));
                }

                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "err: " + error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("data", "value");

            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(sr);

    return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        /* --- Adding the Listener here --- */
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                //Food food = this.foods.get(position);
                Log.i(TAG, "Clicked!");
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

And this will be your **RecyclerItemClickListener.java** file:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener  implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;


    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }


    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
        if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Hey Thanks @Somendra for the advice. I think it is on the right path, however it is only retrieving one item now. I have three items, and the "click" log seems to be appearing for the length of three, but only one card appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the click listener on the specific element.
For example if you want to do something when you click on the image then :

You need to call `holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(this);`

Try this !!

If you want to set the click listener to the entire row, then you might want to set the click listener on the root element of your row item.

Answer (score 0):

**handling clicks for the entire item "the viewholder"**

**1.  create custom listener**

```
    public class RecyclerClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
}
```

**2. listen for clicks using our listener** inside your

```
  recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
   //use getActivity() if you are using fragment instead of MyActivity.this
            new RecyclerClickListener(MyActivity.this, recyclerView, new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Food food= foodList.get(position);
                    //do whatever 

                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // to be implement add to favourite
                }
            })


    );
```

---

**if you are listening to a specifc item inside the view holder.**

1.create an inner interface inside your adapter and create an instance of it.

```
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
       public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Food item);
        }


               //and also the constructor 
               public MyAdapter(List<Food> foodList,Context ctx,OnItemClickListener 
               listener){
          // ......
          this.mListener=mListener;
    }
```

2.inside your viewholder class create `setListener()` method

```
            public void SetListener(final Food item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {


            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override public void onClick(View v) {

                    listener.onItemClick(item);

                }

            });

        }
```

3.inside you `onBindView`

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FoodViewHolder holder, int position) { 
    //...
    viewHolder.setListener(foodList.get(position), mListener);
      }
```

4.inside your activity or fragment

```
 MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(foodList,getActivity(),new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(Food item){


              }
          });
```